# How can i avoid unsafe eval in my Content Security Policy

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy

I have read the answers to how to fix `unsafe eval` being needed in my Content Security Policy due to using setTimeout by using an anonymous function.

However I use a script that contains the following:-

```
$ = function (a) {
return /^f/.test(typeof a) ? /in/.test(b.readyState) ? setTimeout('$('+a+')', 9) : a() : new i(a)
}
```

and I cannot for the life of me work out how to convert it into a script that uses an anonymous function, or if there is a way to rewrite it.

The code is part of [ki.js](https://github.com/dciccale/ki.js) if you need to see more of the code.

I tried

```
return /^f/.test(typeof a) ? /in/.test(b.readyState) ? setTimeout(function(){'$('+a+')'}, 9) : a() : new i(a)
```

but that obviously wasn't going to work! I think I am just sleep deprived but can someone point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use a string reference if you're gonna use your own anonymous function. Just use normal code inside.

(Not sure about that content security policy thing though, just helping with the syntax. If that doesn't completely solve the question I'll remove the answer and post this as a comment.)

```
$ = function (a) {
  return /^f/.test(typeof a) 
    ? /in/.test(b.readyState) 
      ? setTimeout(function() { $(a); }, 9) 
      : a() 
    : new i(a);
};
```

Comment: Some times you just need to admit you are being thick and let someone else point out your stupidity, thanks bud, it also passes CSP as it is no longer eval.

Comment: No worries, we all have our little moments of confusion. Glad to help.